# IE 10, when I click on Compatibility button, everything moves to left

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Problem is when I click on compatibility button or in developer tools try to view page in IE 7,8 or 9

When I click on compatibility button (next to URL area) in IE 10, all of the controls on my page, float towards to left.

Not sure what could be wrong, I also tried browser Mode to IE 9, 8  and 7 and still everything stays on left.

I also noticed as soon as refresh page (while being in compatibility mode) everything gets normal.

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="headertext">
                    <div>SomeeeeeeeeText</div>
                    <div class="bp">SomeTexttttttttttttttttttttttt</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Segoe, Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #0783FF;
    color: #fff;    
}

#outer {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#content {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#header>img, #headertext {
    display: inline-block;
}

#headertext {
    text-align: left;
}

#headertext .bp {
    font-size: 2.6em;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

Updating

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wGnV/)

Comment: If you don't have an example, we're going to have a hard time helping you.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine updated with fiddle

Comment: Don't click the Compatibility button then.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Is there any way I can tell that to clients :) , however problem seems to be with viewing on IE 8,9 and 7 too i guess

Comment: Actually, yes. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: Not sure but I heard of problems with older IE's and `display: table-cell;`

Comment: @j08691 it's <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "">

Answer (score 1):

Your layout uses relatively modern CSS features like `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. These have only been supported since IE8.

However, "Compatibility Mode" will often switch Internet Explorer to Quirks Mode, which is basically IE5.5 mode. I suspect that `display: table` and `display: table-cell` do not work here: They were invented after IE5.5 was released.

So really, you have two choices:

1. Change your doctype to either HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) or HTML 4.01 Strict (`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`) and render in Standards Mode. I'd recommend doing this.
2. Change your CSS to use technology that was available in IE5.5. Basically, that means using `float` for layout and fighting with the box model (the way width is calculated is is different between IE and other browsers).

**Edit:**

If (as inferred from a comment on [one of your other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133939/document-mode-in-ie-10)) you want to vertically centre the `#content` box, try setting `html, body { height: 100%; }`. In standards mode, `height: 100%;` means 100% of the height of the parent element. If html and/or body are only as tall as the content, it won't get vertically centred on the screen.

Comment: Thank You, I added meta for x-ua0Compatible instead, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133939/document-mode-in-ie-10

Comment: add x-ua-compatble... bit to your answer and I will accept it, and you are right about the bug in my other question, you might want to answer there as well. Thank You

Comment: I added attribute body { height: 100%; } but nothing really changes