# Document Mode in IE 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

I added this to hide compatibility button, which worked perfectly fine;

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
```

But Document Mode: comes as `Standards (Page Default)` when what I want is `"Document Mode: Quirks"`

Answer (score 1):

By hiding the compatibility button, you are claiming that your page is standards-compliant.

Wanting to use Quirks Mode while stating that your page is standards-compliant is an oxymoron.

If your page uses Quirks Mode, set `IE=5.5`. Otherwise, fix your page to actually be standards-compliant.

Comment: Thank You Niet, but how would I know where is the problem, everything works nice except div keeps staying on the top, in quirks mode div is in middle of page

Comment: Here is the code and fiddle link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112659/ie-10-when-i-click-on-compatibility-button-everything-moves-to-left

Comment: problem was with parent height not set and div's height as 100%, so changed div's position to absolute and added overflow to hidden